# When was the k-means clustering algorithm first used?

Tags: references, data-mining, k-means, history

K-means is probably one of the most used algorithms for clustering. I was looking for bibliography for its first use, but it has been around a lot, so what's the first one?  Also, when was the algorithm first named "k-means"?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Are you asking what was the first study (historically) to have used k-means clustering?

Comment: yes, and when was declared for the first time as "k-means"

Comment: [History of $k$-means on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#History).

Comment: Note that the history on wikipedia probably isn't complete.  You will need to do more research yourself. In some reference - which I unfortunately did not keep - some earlier resources were mentioned.

Comment: This reference should interest people interested in this thread: Bock, Hans-Hermann. 2008 Origins and extensions of the k-means algorithm in cluster analysis  _Electronic Journ@l for History of
Probability and Statistics_ 4(2) http://www.jehps.net/Decembre2008/Bock.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the best of my [knowledge](http://www.jehps.net/Decembre2008/Bock.pdf), the name 
'k-means' was first used in [MacQueen (1967)](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bsmsp/1200512992). The name refers to the improved algorithm proposed in that paper and not to the original one. Section 3 of that paper contains an application 
(which is missing from earlier papers such as Steinhaus (1956)).

- J. MacQueen (1967). Some methods for classification and analysis of multivariate observations. Proc. Fifth Berkeley Symp. on Math. Statist. and Prob., Vol. 1 (Univ. of Calif. Press, 1967), 281--297.
- Steinhaus (1956). Sur la division des corps mat ́eriels en parties.
  Bulletin de l’Académie Polonaise des Sciences, Classe III, vol. IV, no. 12, 801-804.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently reproduced a version of Hugo Steinhaus paper: [Sur la division des corps matériels en parties](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/Documents/Steinhaus_H_1956_j-bull-acad-polon-sci_division_cmp-k-means.pdf) (On the division of material bodies into parts). The conclusion (originally in French) is (somehow):

> Diverse questions, for instance those about types in anthropology, or
>   others with practical motivations, like those of industrial object
>   normalization, require a solution based on the determination of $n$ 
>   fictitious representatives  of a numerous population, chosen so as to
>   minimize as much as possible the deviations between population
>   elements  and those from the sample. The deviation is mesured between
>   every actual element and the closest fictitious element.

I can only guess that it was used at least a such closely thereafter, but the history did not keep track. In his paper, H. Steinhaus uses $A_i$ to name centroids (means), and $K_i$ refers to each of the $n$ sub-bodies (possibly from German [Körper](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/K%C3%B6rper), [the letter $K$ for fields being in use in mathematics since R. Dedekind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#History)).

MacQueen's 1967 paper motivated the name:

> The $k$-means concept represents a generalization of the ordinary
>   sample mean, and one is naturally led to study the pertinent
>   asymptotic behavior, the object being to establish some sort of law of
>   large numbers for the $k$-means.

Comment: I'd guess that $k$ is just a conventional choice for a constant number of  classes, $n$ being already bespoke for most statistical people as number of observations.

Comment: Indded, in McQueen's paper, the number of classes is $k$

Answer (score 0):

Another early paper showing K-Means clustering was published by Ball and Hall in 1965 [1].  A K-Means like algorithm was part of their ISODATA algorithm. They went further to implement an iterative cluster split/merge phase in order to arrive at a "best" number of clusters.  Pure K-Means takes the number of centroids as a given.

[1] Ball, G.H. and Hall, D.J. (1965) "ISODATA, a Novel Method of Data Analysis and Pattern Classification." Stanford Research Institute, Menlo Park